# Scheme: Number of occurrences in a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a Scheme function called "p" with one parameter X which is a list of letters. the function should return true if the number of a's is one less than the number of b's. This is what I have but can't get around argument errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#lang scheme

(define p
(lambda (X)
(let ((countA 0))
(let ((countB 0))
(count(countA countB X)
(if (= countA (- countB 1))
#t
#f))))))

(define count
(lambda (A B X)
(if (null? (cdr X))
(car X)
((if (string=? "a" (car X))
((+ A 1) (p(cdr X)))
((if (string=? "b" (car X))
((+ B 1) (p(cdr X)))
(p(cdr X)))))))))
```

Comment: This code has so many errors... parenthesis problems, procedure call problems. I'd suggest you start over from the beginning and test throughly each procedure in turn, before even posting this as a question

Comment: I'm not getting any parenthesis problems just argument errors

Comment: Robbie: believe me, there are _several_ parenthesis problems with the code. For instance: it's wrong to put double parenthesis around an `if`. Follow my advice, start from scratch, write a little functionality at first, and test it, test it over and over to get it right before moving to the next part of the solution.

Comment: Also, forget about the `let` form for this problem, that's not the way to solve it. And you're incorrectly assuming that the parameters passed to the `count` procedure will somehow store the result after `count` returns - that's not right, it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting this is a homework. If it weren't, this is the idiomatic way to solve it:

```
(define (p lst)
  (= (count-letters "a" lst)
     (- (count-letters "b" lst) 1)))

(define (count-letters letter lst)
  (count (lambda (e) (string=? e letter))
         lst))
```

... But of course, you're expected to solve it by hand. Some feedback on your code:

- There are multiple misplaced parenthesis
- In particular, it's incorrect to put double parenthesis around an `if`
- The way you're using `let` for this problem is incorrect, it *might* work if you were mutating the value of the variables defined in the `let`s, but I really doubt that's the best approach to write the solution in this case
- You're incorrectly assuming that the parameters passed to the `count` procedure will somehow store the result after `count` returns - that's not right, it won't work like that

Take ideas from the above code to write your own solution - first, you need to define a `count-letters` function that *doesn't* use `count` and that, for a given letter, counts the number of times it occurs in the list. With that procedure in hand, it's pretty easy to write the `p` procedure (in fact, you can just snarf my implementation above!). Don't forget to test it:

```
(p '("a" "b" "b"))
=> #t
(p '("a" "a" "b" "b"))
=> #f
```

Comment: Ah I see the errors of my previous code (basically a clusterfluff) I started over from scratch like you suggested and used your idea and now it works. Thanks a bunch!!